# Blocking upload window pop up using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

If the input values have been entered only then the user should be able to upload file.But as soon as i click on button the window to upload files pops up.I do not want it to pop up unless user have input the values in input files stated below.
These are inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Enter Audit ID" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="email_id_upload"  placeholder="Enter Email_id " autocomplete="off">
```

This is uploader:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="button" name="submit_file" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this is Js to check if the user have input all the values:

```
   $('#file').click(function(){

        var email_id_upload= $('#email_id_upload').val();
      var id =  $('#id').val();
        if(email_id_upload.length !==0 &&  id.lenght !==0)
        {
        //allow upload window to pop up

         }
        else
            {
                if(email_id_upload.length ===0 && id.length ===0)
                {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id and audit id</span>");}
                else{
                if(email_id_upload.length ===0)
                {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id</span>");}
                if(id.length ===0)
                {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id and audit id</span>");}
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: add `return false` in the click function wherever you want to block the click from doing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have posted your JS, it actually works for me. There is one typo in your if condition: `id.lenght`. In general, it's not a good idea to just bind to the click event, because someone might also trigger e.g. the submit event, by pressing enter inside a form field.

In your example, when both fields are empty and someone clicks the #file element, the else block is executed, and the click event bubbles up to the container of the #file element. To stop event bubbling, return false at the end of your else block.

Answer (score 1):

I, just correct ur script. Think it will be work:

```
$('#file').click(function(e){

    var email_id_upload= $('#email_id_upload').val();
  var id =  $('#id').val();
    if(email_id_upload.length !==0 &&  id.lenght !==0)
    {
    //allow upload window to pop up

     }
    else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(email_id_upload.length ===0 && id.length ===0)
            {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id and audit id</span>");}
            else{
            if(email_id_upload.length ===0)
            {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id</span>");}
            if(id.length ===0)
            {$('#message_content2_1').html("<span style='color:red'>Please fill email id and audit id</span>");}
            }
        }
});
```